# Database only or server app + database?

Tags: c#, c++, database, postgresql, server

I've got situation where I need to expose some services to outer entity. All services do is:
1. take arguments from service caller
2. query database
3. delete queried data from db
4. return queried data back to caller

I'm trying to decide if I need to make server application which will access database, or just make database procedures. Functionally, both ways satisfies me. What I'm concerned of is security and I don't have much experience administrating postgresql database.
If I expose database procedures, how much administration I can do? Can I limit number of queries(procedure calls) user can issue? Can I limit time between 2 queries(procedure calls) and amount of memory user can use?
Services would return approximately 5MB of data and they would be called about few times per hour. Even tho service user is trusted and connection between user and server would be VPN'd, I need some kind of query rate limiting, just to be safe.